# What is the best speech recognition software for dictation in Ubuntu?

Tags: speech-recognition

As a writer and editor, I am typing a lot. What would be the best speech recognition software (free and/or purchasable) to help me typing? I am used to Dragon in Windows 10 , but I am converting to Ubuntu.